# Can't use git with aptana

Tags: git, aptana

When i try to put something on a git server it's givin' me an error:
"Reference to undefined variable USER"

In bash: echo $USER giving me correct answer.

What could it be?

It's eclipse with aptana-3 plugin (a whole pack)

Comment: do you have your rsa key configured?

Comment: Yes I have. Git from console works excellent

Answer (score 2):

A bash session might have the correct environment variable set.

But the native OS session might not (like a DOS session on Windows for instance).
Can you launch your aptana from a session which has just before set the correct value for `USER`?

If it still fails (like in [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=461002&)), try also to set the correct value for `$HOME`.

Comment: It still fails to work. 
The same error. 

I have even exported USER and HOME values before running

Comment: Strange. Did you try to reproduce the problem with a classic Eclipse installation and Egit (http://code.google.com/p/egit/wiki/EGitQuickGuide)?

Comment: I didn't but i think i will surrender, i will pushing from console. No time for stupid errors (: and as I remember it is still beta?

Comment: @matiit: I understand. EGit is still pre-1.0 (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ). I prefer console session too ;)

Comment: only commit messages are fancier wit GUI (: and history showing

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Tracked down the issue. Looks like Eclipse is biting on ENV values that contain "${" in the value. A user was changing his command prompt to incude his username, hostname and pwd. After he commented it out of his .profile, it avoided the issue. As a result I added a bugfix to fix that in our development stream that should get into our next release.

--

Looks like a duplicate of https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35272/tickets/1867-git-push-has-encountered-a-problem

I'm not able to replicate the issue, but if you could provide some more details on that ticket I can take a look, since I wrote all of our git support. It's likely that somehow something like $USER is sneaking into the git executable path, and when passed along to the launching infrastructure, it tries to interpret it as an eclipse launching variable (as opposed to a ENV var) that it can't resolve.