# Reference to undefined variable USER (aptana, egit)

Tags: eclipse, aptana, egit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't use git with aptana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488411/cant-use-git-with-aptana)

I know it was erlier but i didn't find any working solution.
And i need it for yesterday ;/

It's aptana studio 3 and EGIT.

That error shows when i try to use egit (example: pull)

Please help, save my life (:

And I use Linux (Archlinux).